# File Repository (with file history) - What implementation to use?

Tags: filesystems, repository

I'm writing a file backup utility that:
(1) Backs up your current files; and 
(2) Allows you to retrieve past versions of such files (similar to code repository revisions).

I'm considering using a source code repository (SVN, Git, Mercurial are main candidates) since they provide similar functionality, except to source code.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of that compared to writing my own proprietary code (e.g. for each file, keep the current file and maintain a binary diff chain down to the oldest revision)?

What method would you recommend, in light of performance considerations?

If it matters, the server program will be written in Python, with performance-critical areas done by C extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement can be done perfectly using a source code repository. You can just reuse them.

Many project is open source, you can modify them if you want.

EDIT:

For small frequently commits, I think it depends on the frequency and how large the repository is. If the repository is very large and committed frequently, then I think it is very difficult to reach your goal. But if the number of files to back up is not large or the frequency is not high, then it will be OK.

Comment: Can you explain the performance implications? Source code repositories may be expecting commits/pushes a few times a day, but a file system might have file updates every second. Would a repository handle this load (many, many small commits) well?